# Create a function to search for a Composer by name in the dataset

Tags: python

Guys just a bit stuck with my code..if someone can help me i'd really appreciate it

Q1.Create a function to search for a Composer by name in the dataset. Since a Composer could exist multiple times, the function should return a list of the appropriate "BL record IDs" related to the Composer.

```py
import csv

def searchname(userdata):
  with open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      found = False
      for row in reader:
           if row['Composer']==userdata:
             found = True
 return list()
 print(result)

uinput = input('Search for Composer: ')
searchname(uinput)
```

Comment: If you could include the first 5-6 lines of your csv file, it would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: `list()` creates empty list. You should create list before loop - ie. `results = list()` and append rows to this list - ie. `results.append(row)` or `results.append(row["ID"])` - and later `return result`

Comment: `print()` after `return` will be never executed because `return` exits function at once.

Comment: BL record ID Composer Composer life dates Title Publication date (standardised) Publication date (not standardised) Place of publication Publisher ISBN ISMN Publisher number BL shelfmark
1279866   The Penguin book of Canadian Folk songs 1973 1973 Harmondsworth Penguin Books 140708421   mH00/3305 ; X.439/3548
1312079   Anthology for The musician's guide to theory and analysis 2005 c2005 New York WW Norton & Co 393925765   F.1946.h
1706700 Hofhaimer, Paul 1459-1537 Harmoniae poeticae Pauli Hofheimeri : viri equestri dignitate insigni, ac musici excellentis, quales sub

Comment: Thank for your help Pakpe.. i copied paste the first 5 lines but it looks confusing...

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Answer (score -1):

Just change 'n' to be the column where you'd find the composer name.  You also might need to normalize capital/non-capital letters since you're dealing with user inputs ...

Also, I just output the entire row of data, you can specifically add what you want to your list if the file has too much data.

```
def searchname(userdata):
    list = []
    for line in open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', 'r'):
      row = line.split(',')
      if row[n] == userdata:
          list.append(line)
    return(list)

uinput = input('Search for Composer: ')
print(searchname(uinput))
```

Comment: Thank Kyle.. I run it but got an error :(((

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5e388bf04b42> in <module>()
      8 
      9 uinput = input('Search for Composer: ')
---> 10 print(searchname(uinput))
     11 

<ipython-input-33-5e388bf04b42> in searchname(userdata)
      3     for line in open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', 'r'):
      4       row = line.split(',')
----> 5       if row[n] == userdata:
      6           list.append(line)
      7     return(list)

NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: Of course, you got an error.  I don't know what your csv file looks like or any tangible data that would allow me to give you functioning code.  This is just an idea of how you might achieve what you're looking to do.  share 10 lines of your csv file and I'll tell you how to make it work ...

Comment: Thank for your answer. i can share the first lines but it will look a bit messy...

Comment: BL record ID Composer Composer life dates Title Publication date (standardised) Publication date (not standardised) Place of publication Publisher ISBN ISMN Publisher number BL shelfmark 1279866 The Penguin book of Canadian Folk songs 1973 1973 Harmondsworth Penguin Books 140708421 mH00/3305 ; X.439/3548 1312079 Anthology for The musician's guide to theory and analysis 2005 c2005 New York WW Norton & Co 393925765 F.1946.h 1706700 Hofhaimer, Paul 1459-1537 Harmoniae poeticae Pauli Hofheimeri : viri equestri dignitate insigni, ac musici excellentis, quales sub –

Comment: So basically there are many composers with the same name and the question asks me look for a composer and then append the appropriate Bl record id as a list...(since one composer has multimple record ids...)

Answer (score -1):

You should create empty list before `for`-loop. And inside `for`-loop you should `append()` row (or `row["ID"]`) to this list. And later you should return this list.

And you shouldn't use `print()` after `return` because it will be never executed because `return` exits functions at once.

```
def searchname(userdata):
    results = list()
    with open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['Composer'] == userdata:
                results.append(row)
    return results

# --- main ---

uinput = input('Search for Composer: ')
results = searchname(uinput)
print(results)
```

---

**BTW:**

Sometimes it is good to convert to `lower()` or `upper()` to correctly compare strings

```
if row['Composer'].lower() == userdata.lower():
```

because strings can be in different size.

Sometimes it is good to check if string is only part of other string

```
if userdata.lower() in row['Composer'].lower():
```

because user may give only part of name.

Sometimes text may have whitespaces (spaces, tabs, enters) at the ends of string and it is good to remove it using `strip()`

```
if userdata.strip().lower() in row['Composer'].strip().lower():
```

---

```
def searchname(userdata):
    results = list()
    with open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if userdata.strip().lower() in row['Composer'].strip().lower():
                results.append(row)
    return results

# --- main ---

uinput = input('Search for Composer: ')
results = searchname(uinput)
print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.. i run it but it returns an empty list....do u have any idea why is that?

Comment: Search for Composer: Paul
[]

Comment: I don't have your data so I can't test it and answer for this problem but there can be few problems. 1) you may have `paul` or `PAUL` in database and you have to use `lower()` to compare `paul` with `paul`. 2) you may have `Paul LastName` and then you have to use `in` instead of `==` because you can't compare `"Paul" == "Paul LastName"` - you need `"Paul" in "Paul LastName"`. 3) you may have whitechars (space, tab, enter) in database - which you don't see on screen but they change everything - ie you can't compare `"Paul{spaces}" == "Paul"` - and you may need `strip()` to remove these spaces.

Comment: I saw your data in other comment  (better put it in question - it will be more readable) and you have to use `in` instead of `==`  for this - ie. `"Paul" in "Hofhaimer, Paul"` gives `True` but `"Paul" == "Hofhaimer, Paul"` gives `False`. BTW: to make sure: it needs `userdata in row["Composer"]` instead of `row["Composer"] in userdata`